# Input Validation and wrong output

Tags: java

Right now when I am reading from a file that contains

```
3
6
8 9 11
-123
7
12,
```

The output is

```
3 - prime, palindrome, emirp
6 - even, palindrome,
8 - even, palindrome,
-123 - invalid input
7 - invalid input
```

However, `7` should not be an invalid input and `12,` is skipped entirely which should be displayed as an invalid input. I don't know how to write the code for treating `12,`, `12.` or `12-` as invalid but not having my program treat every last number in my file as an invalid input.

Thank you for the help already!

Here is the part of the code I am working with right now

```
if (inputFile.exists()) {
    Scanner read = new Scanner(inputFile);

    while (read.hasNextInt()) {
        int number = read.nextInt();
        if (number <=0 || !read.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println(number + " - invalid input");
        } else {
            System.out.print(number + " - ");
            if(isEven(number))
                System.out.print("even, ");
            if(isPrime(number))
                System.out.print("prime, ");
            if(isPalin(number))
                System.out.print("palindrome, ");
            if(isEmirp(number))
                System.out.print("emirp");
            System.out.println();
            read.nextLine();
        }
    }
    read.close();
}
```

edited code:

```
while (read.hasNext()) { // continue while there are tokens left
if (read.hasNextInt()) { // check if next token is int
int number = read.nextInt(); // get next int token
if (number <= 0) {System.out.println(number + " - invalid input");}
else{
System.out.print(number + " " + "- ");
if(isEven(number)){
System.out.print("even"+","+ " ");}
if(isPrime(number)){
System.out.print("prime"+ "," +" ");}
if(isPalin(number)){
System.out.print("palindrome"+"," + " ");}
if(isEmirp(number)){
System.out.print("emirp");}

else { 
String s = read.next(); 
System.out.print(s + " - invalid input");
System.out.println("");
read.nextLine();
```

Comment: Please update your question by adding the source code that you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the reason `7` is flagged as invalid in this line:

```
if (number <= 0 || !read.hasNextInt()) {
```

The next token is `12,` which is not a valid int. That's why this expression results in `true` and why `7` is flagged as invalid. To correct this, replace the above line with this line:

```
if (number <= 0) {
```

**EDIT**

The main while loop only continues if the next token is an `int`. For `12,` however, that's not the case. You have to make a few alterations to make this work the way you want to:

```
while (read.hasNext()) { // continue while there are tokens left
    if (read.hasNextInt()) { // check if next token is int
        int number = read.nextInt(); // get next int token
        if (number <= 0) {
            System.out.println(number + " - invalid input");
        } else {
            // etc...
        }
    } else { // next token is not int
        String s = read.next(); // get next non-int token
        System.out.println(s + " - invalid input"); // print invalid input
    }
}
```

Comment: okay i understand but how do i treat the number 12, different from just the number 12 ?

Comment: @Noah, ah yes forgot that part of the question. I will make an edit to further explain.

Comment: the concept makes sense to me but when i am adding this block of code to the end of my code i am not getting anything as my output when my file only contains the number 12,

Comment: @Noah, you mustn't put it after the other code. This is a replacement for your own while loop. Put your own checks in at `// etc...`.

Comment: I added it and it works but now it is formatted weird and I do not really understand why it is doing it. Maybe i am just not understanding where i am supposed to put it.

Comment: i am gonna edit my code from above so you can see what i did

Comment: @Noah, I think there has to be one extra `}` before the last `else`.

Comment: but then i would have an else statement without and if